# Revoke Apple account access in Android using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, revoke-token, apple-authentication

I have implemented apple account authentication in Android by using Firebase

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/apple

We have to revoke the access for apple account in our application. For iOS, authorisation code can be fetched from Firebase/apple SDK and can revoke the access by using JWT code. Below is the reference link

https://github.com/jooyoungho/apple-token-revoke-in-firebase

In Android, we can get only Firebase Auth Token ID.

How can we fetch authorisation code for Android apple account sign in or do we have any other way to revoke the access/tokens from apple signin account by using Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want to keep the user account with one or more other sign-in methods and only unlink the user's Apple sign-in.

This might be what you are looking for: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking#unlink-an-auth-provider-from-a-user-account

```java
FirebaseAuth
  .getInstance()
  .getCurrentUser()
  .unlink("apple.com");
```

Comment: Thanks @Dennis Alund for your post. The problem here is after signout from our application, automatically we have to stop using apple account for our application. Able to revoke the access manually after we sign in to apple.com and select SignIn with Apple and stop using account. This we have to do programatically instead of manually.